# How to convert a list of dictionary into a python panda dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with an API that will respond to me a list of dictionaries. the number of dictionaries in the list will vary but I need to convert the response into a pandas dataframe so that I can manipulate the data. Here is a sample of the response. How can I make a panda dataframe with headers (ticker, cap, when)

`[{'ticker': 'KMG', 'cap_mm': 'NA', 'when': '--'}, {'ticker': 'SFIX', 'cap_mm': '2,665', 'when': 'amc'}]`

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to a `DataFrame` like as usual, `pd.DataFrame(...)`:

```
>>> lod=[{'ticker': 'KMG', 'cap_mm': 'NA', 'when': '--'}, {'ticker': 'SFIX', 'cap_mm': '2,665', 'when': 'amc'}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(lod)
  cap_mm ticker when
0     NA    KMG   --
1  2,665   SFIX  amc
>>>
```

So remember to try stuff before asking...

Answer (score 0):

simply do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=yourlist)
```

output will be:

```
 cap_mm ticker when
0     NA    KMG   --
1  2,665   SFIX  amc
```